# Why does opening a pdf with pdf.js sometimes leads to the "save as.." dialog instead?

Tags: firefox, pdf.js

I've set firefox to my standard pdf viewer because I've had mostly good experiences with pdf.js.
Unfortunately, some pdfs won't open and the "save as" dialog ins displayed instead. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely because the server explicitly sends `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

There is no reasonable way to override that at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Makes sense as this happens in Foswiki when one opens a page attachment. Also, still the case in July 2014 with Firefox 31.